# get 404 error while working in browser

Tags: javascript, xml, api, lift

I have the following API defined:

```
object api_event extends RestHelper {
       serve {
             case "events" :: Nil XmlGet _ => <b>static</b>
             }
 }
```

Querying from the browser I correctly get the data.

*[INFO] net.liftweb.util.TimeHelpers - Service request (GET) /events returned 200, took 27 Milliseconds*

While from javascript (JQuery) with the following code:

```
  $.get('events', function(data) 
        { alert('Load was performed.');}
   );
```

I get a 404:

*[INFO] net.liftweb.util.TimeHelpers - Service request (GET) /events returned 404, took 816 Milliseconds*

Q: Am I badly doing the request with JQuery?

Comment: just a tip, try using console.log instead of alert for debugging tasks, using alert stops the execution of the script.

Comment: @Cody Thanks, I did not know!

Comment: More information would be needed to debug this. What are the full URLs you are using each time? There is a difference between `/events` and `events`... but by the looks of it your debug already states that they are both requesting `/events`. As mentioned by Cody, you could use the 'net' section of whatever console your browser supports to get more feedback about the ajax request - i.e. using FireBug.

Answer (score 0):

Even if from browser is allowed to do the request /events and get the correct result, from Js the call request has to be:

```
$.get('events.xml', function(data) 
        { alert('Load was performed.');}
   );
```

so I had to specify the .xml